# How to change the alignment of a UISearchBar according to the input language

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, uisearchbar

I would like to be able to input text in either Left-to-Right and Right-to-Left languages into a UISearchBar. This means that once a user has started inputing text in right to left languages, I would like the text alignment to be to the right and vice versa.

The question is - Is there any way to catch these events of language switching? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You want to subscribe to `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification`. See the [UITextInputMode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputmode).

Comment: Updated link for UITextInputMode Class - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputmode

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in ViewDidLoad

```
    searchbar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func customizeSearchBar() {
            //For placeHolder to allign Right
            searchBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            // for text field to align right
             if let textfield = searchBarText.value(forKey: "searchField") as? 
            UITextField {
                 textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                 textfield.textAlignment = .right

                 if let leftView = textfield.leftView as? UIImageView {
                     leftView.image = leftView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                     leftView.tintColor = UIColor.clear
                 }
             }
        }
```