# Right Align UISearchbar placeholder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar, ios10

This code used to work, but after ios 10 it has stopped functioning:

```
UITextField *searchTextField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
searchTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight
```

I have tried both paragraph and attributedPlaceholder, but the placeholder is always left aligned. The bug appears in xcode 7 and 8. How can I resolve this?

Comment: refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394489/is-is-possible-to-change-a-uisearchbar-placeholders-alignment.

Comment: it's not working...

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this a long time, here is the solution

**Swift**

```
searchBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `UISearchBar` if you need to do these kinds of customizations. You'll have to make your own using a `UITextField` and a `UIImageView`, and responding to the `delegate` calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you use searchBar in NavigationBar or not, this solution works in both cases:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
searchBar.searchTextField.textAlignment = .right
```